# Find records, which have several specific records in a joined table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables as follows:

```
create table gift_certificate
(
    id               int auto_increment
        primary key,
    name             varchar(64)       not null,
    description      mediumtext        not null,
    price            decimal default 0 not null,
    duration         int     default 1 not null,
    create_date      datetime          not null,
    last_update_date datetime          not null
)
```

and

```
create table tag
(
    id   int auto_increment
        primary key,
    name varchar(64) not null,
    constraint tag_name_uindex
        unique (name)
)
```

with a linking table:

```
create table gift_certificate__tag
(
    certificate_id int not null,
    tag_id         int not null,
    primary key (certificate_id, tag_id),
    constraint gift_certificate__tag_gift_certificate_id_fk
        foreign key (certificate_id) references gift_certificate (id),
    constraint gift_certificate__tag_tag_id_fk
        foreign key (tag_id) references tag (id)
)
```

I need to search for gift certificates by several tags (“and” condition). I only came up with a solution for one tag

```
select distinct gc.*, tag.* from gift_certificate gc
    left outer join gift_certificate__tag joint on gc.id=joint.certificate_id
    left outer join tag on joint.tag_id=tag.id
    where tag.name='puppy'
    order by gc.id desc;
```

Would be grateful for some support

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can aggregate the joint table by certificate and use `HAVING` to only keep certificates that have all the tags. Then select all matching certificates using an `IN` clause. For instance:

```
select *
from gift_certificate
where id in
(
  select joint.certificate_id 
  from gift_certificate__tag joint
  join tag on joint.tag_id=tag.id
  group by joint.certificate_id
  having max(case when tag.name = 'puppy' then 1 else 0 end) = 1
     and max(case when tag.name = 'something' then 1 else 0 end) = 1
);
```

As true = 1 and false = 0 in MySQL, you can shorten the expression to

```
  having max(tag.name = 'puppy')
```

if you find this readable. Or

```
  having sum(tag.name = 'puppy') > 0
```